# How to convert Time String to Seconds and get the Average .Also the return should be in Time String format using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sample Data :

MyTable

| TargetTime(HH:MM:SS |
| --- |
| 00:11:02 |
| 00:02:00 |

It should be like this

(Time String convert to seconds )

Average()

Return format should be in : HH:MM:SS

I have tried some similar answers here but it only converts to seconds and it seems that it's not getting the proper Average also not the return that im expecting.Thanks.

Comment: I think you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why store it as string? Why not store the value in a datetime data type?

Comment: Is the HH:MM:SS capped to 24 hours, or can be more?

Comment: @gotqn within 24 hours only ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try and build on this:

```
WITH DataSource AS 
(
  SELECT '00:11:02' AS TargetTime
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '00:02:00'
), 
AvgTimeInSeconds AS
(
  SELECT CAST(AVG(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(TargetTime AS TIME)) * 3600 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(TargetTime AS TIME)) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CAST(TargetTime AS TIME))) AS INT64) AS TimeSeconds
  FROM DataSource
)
SELECT make_interval(second => TimeSeconds)
FROM AvgTimeInSeconds
```

[image]